# coldfusion cfinclude before and after callbacks

Tags: coldfusion

Is there any possibility to call some callback function for Debugging purpose before and after the `cfinclude` tag.

for example if i have

```
<cfinclude template="xyz.cfm" />
```

and is Logging is enabled, I would like to call abefoeInclude and afterInclude callbacks.

Is there a possibility to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own version of cfinclude as a custom tag http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=reuseCode_2.html

Inside that you can check if debugging is turned on using isDebugMode() and do your logging in side the custom tag. Then you can use the custom tag instead of cfinclude.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean whether debugging is enabled? You use the ColdFusion function isDebugMode().

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7bf4.html